# Element Buffer Object size for shared VAO

Tags: opengl, vertex-buffer, vao, buffer-objects

I want to store my indexed geometry in a shared vao.

If the current vao is full, I create another vao together with the buffers for the layouts (Pos, Normals, Uvs, etc..). I create them with a capacity for say, N vertices. (Could be thousands, I want to share the max amount of similar geometry I can)

The problem is that I don't know how much size to allocate for the Element Buffer Object that should back the indexed vao.

Is there a common practice for this?

I need a single EBO for each VAO because I want to draw the whole batch with a glMultiDrawElements call, so the batch must have the indices in the same EBO.

Comment: "*I want to draw the whole batch with a glMultiDrawElements call*" So, wouldn't that mean that you're using the *same* VAO for all of the objects? Also, VAO's don't get "full", so it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: VAO's don't get full but the array buffers bounded to it surely can become full. So, whenever I create a VAO, I create also the buffers for the layouts and then i start to load geometry inside them. At a certain point in the program, i can load more geometry and those buffers become full. Therefore i create a new VAO with it's owns buffers bounded to  it.

Comment: The size of indices buffer depends on rendering with triangle-strip, fan, independat, etc.